# Microsoft Access SQL query count distinct

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a queries in MS Access SQL that performs two separate counts function and have drafted the below code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Name, Count(A.Name) AS X, Count(b.Address) AS Y
FROM PEOPLE AS A INNER JOIN PEOPLE Sub AS b ON A.PID = b.PID
GROUP BY A.Nam
```

The problem with this query is that both count functions provide a total count of the number of address for each name and I want the first count function to provide a count of names, therefore I would be grateful if someone could advise how I amend this code to change the first count function to a count distinct

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is wrong - GROUP BY must have A.Name - i think it´s an error by copying.

Otherwise change this. What happens if you do it without DISTINCT? Try it with SUM not with COUNT.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct in your query is obsolete because of the GROUP BY clause.

Furthermore it is not clear if your 'People sub' refers to another table or is a self-join. The following code should work:

```
SELECT P.Name
, COUNT(P.*) AS X
, COUNT(DISTINCT A.Address) AS Y
FROM PEOPLE AS P 
INNER JOIN ADDRESS AS A ON A.PID = P.PID
GROUP BY P.Name
```